# C Pthreads Problem, Can't Pass the Info I Want?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pthreads, startup

So I'm trying to make it so the threads startup function opens a file that was given via commandline, one file for each thread, but I also need the startup function to get my results array. So basically I need to get a string (the filename) and a 2D array of results to my startup thread some how, I'm thoroughly confused.

Anyone have any tips or ideas? Thanks.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"


void* func(void *args);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int nthreads = 0;
    int i = 0;
    long **results;

    printf("Enter number of threads to use:\n> ");
    scanf("%d", nthreads);

    pthread_t threadArray[nthreads];

    // results 2d array; 3 rows by nthreads cols
    results = malloc((nthreads*4) * sizeof(long *));   

    for(i = 0; i<nthreads; i++) {
       pthread_create(&threadArray[i], NULL, wordcount, HELP!!!!); 
    } 

    for(i = 0; i<nthreads; i++) {
       pthread_join(threadArray[i], NULL);
    } 

    pthread_exit();
}

void * func(void *arguments)
{     
     FILE *infile = stdin;
     infile = fopen(filename, "rb");    

     fclose (infile);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally a structure that contains the data for the thread is declared and initialized, and a pointer to that structure is passed as the thread argument.

The thread function then casts the `void*` back to the structure pointer and has at the data.

Just remember that the lifetime of that structure still needs to be valid when the thread gets scheduled (which means you need to be very careful if it's a local variable).  And as Jonathan Leffler pointed out, pass each thread it's own instance of the structure, or be very careful how you reuse it.  Otherwise a thread may read data intended for a different thread if the structure gets reused before the thread is finished with it.

Probably the simplest way to manage those issues is to `malloc()` a structure for each thread, initialize it, pass the pointer to the thread and let the thread `free()` it when it's done with the data.

Comment: Valid and still containing the intended data - you can't just reuse the same structure with a different value in it for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter to [pthread_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html) can be any object you want, so for example you could have:

```
struct ThreadArguments {
    const char* filename;
    // additional parameters
};

void* ThreadFunction(void* arg) {
    CHECK_NOTNULL(arg);
    ThreadArguments* thread_arg = (ThreadArguments*) arg;
    // now you can access the other parameters through this thread_arg object
    // ...
}

// ...
ThreadArguments* arg = (ThreadArguments*) malloc(sizeof(ThreadArguments));
ret = pthread_create(&thread_id, attributes, &ThreadFunction, arg);
// make sure to check ret
// ...
pthread_join(thread_id);
free(arg);
```

Comment: I want the results array to be shared between the threads though so at the end the threadfunction it puts the results for that thread in the 2D array. If create one variable for the struct and just change the filename then couldn't that mess up the file name for other threads?

Comment: @Billy Reynolds - You are going to malloc a different instance of the struct for each thread.  That allows you to pass to different filenames and the same result array if that is what you want, just change the pointer (or however you choose to do it) to the filename string for each instance.  FWIW, if you aren't comfortable with threads yet then passing the same results array is probably a bad idea.  It will be very easy to get wrong.  It might be better to pass unique result arrays to each thread and just combine them at the end in main (or whatever spawns the threads).